# Where to get Best resources on D language?

Tags: d

Where to get Best resources on D language?

Comment: You also might want to slow down with the questions - give people a chance to answer your first question - [What is D language? (differnce from C/C++/C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985493/what-is-d-language-differnce-from-c-c-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The D Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361) book by by Andrei Alexandrescu
["The Case for D"](http://www.ddj.com/hpc-high-performance-computing/217801225) article by Andrei Alexandrescu
[Official website](http://www.dlang.org)
[Official wiki](http://wiki.dlang.org)

Answer (score 8):

Well, in a few months Andrei Alexandrescu will be releasing his book titled "[The D Programming Language.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361)"  This will likely be a very comprehensive book on version 2 of the language.  Until then, read the docs on digitalmars.com, though they're not all that comprehensive.

Comment: I just finished reviewing the latest draft.  I highly recommend it if you are at all interested in D.

Answer (score 4):

I've found the [D section of the Digital Mars website](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/) and the [newsgroup](http://www.digitalmars.com/webnews/newsgroups.php?search_txt=&group=digitalmars.D) to be very good resources.

Comment: The newsgroup linked above (note it's NOT a forum) is a very good resource. If you use it regularly I would recommend you get a real newsgroup reader app rather than use the web interface.

Answer (score 4):

Study Phobos/Tango sources.

Comment: This is how I learned a lot of the language.  I'd recommend the Phobos sources over the Tango sources.  Tango is mostly written in a Java-like subset of D, whereas Phobos (especially the modules written by Andrei Alexandrescu) is more idiomatic D and shows off more of the language's capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

This book is out: [D Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361), by Andrei Alexandrescu.

I just got it, and can't stop reading it. It's very good, I recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

irc on freenode:

- ## d
- ## d.tango
- ## ldc

for D and tango: [tango](http://www.dsource.org/projects/tango/wiki)

Answer (score 1):

[My response to your other question on D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985493/what-is-d-language-differnce-from-c-c-c/1985535#1985535)

:-)